# WinAPI: How do you get the "Verified Publisher" the UAC shows for signed binaries?

Tags: winapi, wincrypt

I need to verify an .exe and ensure the publisher name matches the expected name (not based on a key since that can change as new code signing certificates are issued, the name is always the same).

I found samples of using `WinVerifyTrust` to verify a signed .exe, but I also need the "*Verified Publisher*" that the UAC shows for signed executables.  How do I get that using the Windows API functions in c or c++ ?

TIA!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by using `WinVerifyTrust` in conjunction with [`CryptQueryObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptqueryobject).

Please note, I did not write this code. I copied this from some site a while ago.. Probably Microsoft or a dev blog. You should simply be able to copy this in to a new C console project and compile/run it.

This is what it outputs:

[image]

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <wintrust.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

#define ENCODING (X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING)

typedef struct {
 LPWSTR lpszProgramName;
LPWSTR lpszPublisherLink;
LPWSTR lpszMoreInfoLink;
} SPROG_PUBLISHERINFO, * PSPROG_PUBLISHERINFO;

BOOL GetProgAndPublisherInfo(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo,
PSPROG_PUBLISHERINFO Info);
BOOL GetDateOfTimeStamp(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo, SYSTEMTIME* st);
BOOL PrintCertificateInfo(PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext);
BOOL GetTimeStampSignerInfo(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo,
PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO* pCounterSignerInfo);

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
    HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
    HCRYPTMSG hMsg = NULL;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
    BOOL fResult;
    DWORD dwEncoding, dwContentType, dwFormatType;
    PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo = NULL;
    PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pCounterSignerInfo = NULL;
    DWORD dwSignerInfo;
    CERT_INFO CertInfo;
    SPROG_PUBLISHERINFO ProgPubInfo;
    SYSTEMTIME st;

    ZeroMemory(&ProgPubInfo, sizeof(ProgPubInfo));
    __try
 {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Usage: SignedFileInfo <filename>\n"));
            return 0;
        }

     # ifdef UNICODE
        lstrcpynW(szFileName, argv[1], MAX_PATH);
     #else
        if (mbstowcs(szFileName, argv[1], MAX_PATH) == -1)
        {
            printf("Unable to convert to unicode.\n");
            __leave;
        }
     #endif

        // Get message handle and store handle from the signed file.
        fResult = CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
        szFileName,
        CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED,
        CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY,
        0,
        &dwEncoding,
        &dwContentType,
        &dwFormatType,
        &hStore,
        &hMsg,
        NULL);
        if (!fResult)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CryptQueryObject failed with %x\n"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // Get signer information size.
        fResult = CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg,
        CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM,
        0,
        NULL,
        &dwSignerInfo);
        if (!fResult)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CryptMsgGetParam failed with %x\n"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // Allocate memory for signer information.
        pSignerInfo = (PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSignerInfo);
        if (!pSignerInfo)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for Signer Info.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Get Signer Information.
        fResult = CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg,
        CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM,
        0,
        (PVOID)pSignerInfo,
        &dwSignerInfo);
        if (!fResult)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CryptMsgGetParam failed with %x\n"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // Get program name and publisher information from 
        // signer info structure.
        if (GetProgAndPublisherInfo(pSignerInfo, &ProgPubInfo))
        {
            if (ProgPubInfo.lpszProgramName != NULL)
            {
                wprintf(L"Program Name : %s\n",
                ProgPubInfo.lpszProgramName);
            }

            if (ProgPubInfo.lpszPublisherLink != NULL)
            {
                wprintf(L"Publisher Link : %s\n",
                ProgPubInfo.lpszPublisherLink);
            }

            if (ProgPubInfo.lpszMoreInfoLink != NULL)
            {
                wprintf(L"MoreInfo Link : %s\n",
                ProgPubInfo.lpszMoreInfoLink);
            }
        }

        _tprintf(_T("\n"));

        // Search for the signer certificate in the temporary 
        // certificate store.
        CertInfo.Issuer = pSignerInfo->Issuer;
        CertInfo.SerialNumber = pSignerInfo->SerialNumber;

        pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStore,
         ENCODING,
         0,
         CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_CERT,
         (PVOID) & CertInfo,
         NULL);
        if (!pCertContext)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertFindCertificateInStore failed with %x\n"),
            GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // Print Signer certificate information.
        _tprintf(_T("Signer Certificate:\n\n"));
        PrintCertificateInfo(pCertContext);
        _tprintf(_T("\n"));

        // Get the timestamp certificate signerinfo structure.
        if (GetTimeStampSignerInfo(pSignerInfo, &pCounterSignerInfo))
        {
            // Search for Timestamp certificate in the temporary
            // certificate store.
            CertInfo.Issuer = pCounterSignerInfo->Issuer;
            CertInfo.SerialNumber = pCounterSignerInfo->SerialNumber;

            pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStore,
             ENCODING,
             0,
             CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_CERT,
             (PVOID) & CertInfo,
             NULL);
            if (!pCertContext)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("CertFindCertificateInStore failed with %x\n"),
                GetLastError());
                __leave;
            }

            // Print timestamp certificate information.
            _tprintf(_T("TimeStamp Certificate:\n\n"));
            PrintCertificateInfo(pCertContext);
            _tprintf(_T("\n"));

            // Find Date of timestamp.
            if (GetDateOfTimeStamp(pCounterSignerInfo, &st))
            {
                _tprintf(_T("Date of TimeStamp : %02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d\n"),
                st.wMonth,
                st.wDay,
                st.wYear,
                st.wHour,
                st.wMinute);
            }
            _tprintf(_T("\n"));
        }
    }
    __finally
 {
        // Clean up.
        if (ProgPubInfo.lpszProgramName != NULL)
            LocalFree(ProgPubInfo.lpszProgramName);
        if (ProgPubInfo.lpszPublisherLink != NULL)
            LocalFree(ProgPubInfo.lpszPublisherLink);
        if (ProgPubInfo.lpszMoreInfoLink != NULL)
            LocalFree(ProgPubInfo.lpszMoreInfoLink);

        if (pSignerInfo != NULL) LocalFree(pSignerInfo);
        if (pCounterSignerInfo != NULL) LocalFree(pCounterSignerInfo);
        if (pCertContext != NULL) CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
        if (hStore != NULL) CertCloseStore(hStore, 0);
        if (hMsg != NULL) CryptMsgClose(hMsg);
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL PrintCertificateInfo(PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext)
{
    BOOL fReturn = FALSE;
    LPTSTR szName = NULL;
    DWORD dwData;

    __try
 {
        // Print Serial Number.
        _tprintf(_T("Serial Number: "));
        dwData = pCertContext->pCertInfo->SerialNumber.cbData;
        for (DWORD n = 0; n < dwData; n++)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("%02x "),
            pCertContext->pCertInfo->SerialNumber.pbData[dwData - (n + 1)]);
        }
        _tprintf(_T("\n"));

        // Get Issuer name size.
        if (!(dwData = CertGetNameString(pCertContext,
        CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
        CERT_NAME_ISSUER_FLAG,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0)))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertGetNameString failed.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Allocate memory for Issuer name.
        szName = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwData * sizeof(TCHAR));
        if (!szName)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for issuer name.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Get Issuer name.
        if (!(CertGetNameString(pCertContext,
        CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
        CERT_NAME_ISSUER_FLAG,
        NULL,
        szName,
        dwData)))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertGetNameString failed.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // print Issuer name.
        _tprintf(_T("Issuer Name: %s\n"), szName);
        LocalFree(szName);
        szName = NULL;

        // Get Subject name size.
        if (!(dwData = CertGetNameString(pCertContext,
        CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0)))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertGetNameString failed.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Allocate memory for subject name.
        szName = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwData * sizeof(TCHAR));
        if (!szName)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for subject name.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Get subject name.
        if (!(CertGetNameString(pCertContext,
            CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
            0,
            NULL,
            szName,
            dwData)))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertGetNameString failed.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Print Subject Name.
        _tprintf(_T("Subject Name: %s\n"), szName);

        fReturn = TRUE;
    }
    __finally
 {
        if (szName != NULL) LocalFree(szName);
    }

    return fReturn;
}

LPWSTR AllocateAndCopyWideString(LPCWSTR inputString)
{
    LPWSTR outputString = NULL;

    outputString = (LPWSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR,
     (wcslen(inputString) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    if (outputString != NULL)
    {
        lstrcpyW(outputString, inputString);
    }
    return outputString;
}

BOOL GetProgAndPublisherInfo(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo,
PSPROG_PUBLISHERINFO Info)
{
    BOOL fReturn = FALSE;
    PSPC_SP_OPUS_INFO OpusInfo = NULL;
    DWORD dwData;
    BOOL fResult;

    __try
 {
        // Loop through authenticated attributes and find
        // SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID OID.
        for (DWORD n = 0; n < pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.cAttr; n++)
        {
            if (lstrcmpA(SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID,
                pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].pszObjId) == 0)
            {
                // Get Size of SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO structure.
                fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID,
                pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                0,
                NULL,
                &dwData);
                if (!fResult)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                    GetLastError());
                    __leave;
                }

                // Allocate memory for SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO structure.
                OpusInfo = (PSPC_SP_OPUS_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwData);
                if (!OpusInfo)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for Publisher Info.\n"));
                    __leave;
                }

                // Decode and get SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO structure.
                fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID,
                pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                0,
                OpusInfo,
                &dwData);
                if (!fResult)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                    GetLastError());
                    __leave;
                }

                // Fill in Program Name if present.
                if (OpusInfo->pwszProgramName)
                {
                    Info->lpszProgramName =
                    AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pwszProgramName);
                }
                else
                    Info->lpszProgramName = NULL;

                // Fill in Publisher Information if present.
                if (OpusInfo->pPublisherInfo)
                {

                    switch (OpusInfo->pPublisherInfo->dwLinkChoice)
                    {
                        case SPC_URL_LINK_CHOICE:
                            Info->lpszPublisherLink =
                            AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pPublisherInfo->pwszUrl);
                            break;

                        case SPC_FILE_LINK_CHOICE:
                            Info->lpszPublisherLink =
                            AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pPublisherInfo->pwszFile);
                            break;

                        default:
                            Info->lpszPublisherLink = NULL;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Info->lpszPublisherLink = NULL;
                }

                // Fill in More Info if present.
                if (OpusInfo->pMoreInfo)
                {
                    switch (OpusInfo->pMoreInfo->dwLinkChoice)
                    {
                        case SPC_URL_LINK_CHOICE:
                            Info->lpszMoreInfoLink =
                            AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pMoreInfo->pwszUrl);
                            break;

                        case SPC_FILE_LINK_CHOICE:
                            Info->lpszMoreInfoLink =
                            AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pMoreInfo->pwszFile);
                            break;

                        default:
                            Info->lpszMoreInfoLink = NULL;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Info->lpszMoreInfoLink = NULL;
                }

                fReturn = TRUE;

                break; // Break from for loop.
            } // lstrcmp SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID 
        } // for 
    }
    __finally
 {
        if (OpusInfo != NULL) LocalFree(OpusInfo);
    }

    return fReturn;
}

BOOL GetDateOfTimeStamp(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo, SYSTEMTIME* st)
{
    BOOL fResult;
    FILETIME lft, ft;
    DWORD dwData;
    BOOL fReturn = FALSE;

    // Loop through authenticated attributes and find
    // szOID_RSA_signingTime OID.
    for (DWORD n = 0; n < pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.cAttr; n++)
    {
        if (lstrcmpA(szOID_RSA_signingTime,
        pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].pszObjId) == 0)
        {
            // Decode and get FILETIME structure.
            dwData = sizeof(ft);
            fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
            szOID_RSA_signingTime,
            pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
            pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
            0,
            (PVOID) & ft,
            &dwData);
            if (!fResult)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                GetLastError());
                break;
            }

            // Convert to local time.
            FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &lft);
            FileTimeToSystemTime(&lft, st);

            fReturn = TRUE;

            break; // Break from for loop.

        } //lstrcmp szOID_RSA_signingTime
    } // for 

    return fReturn;
}

BOOL GetTimeStampSignerInfo(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo, PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO* pCounterSignerInfo)
{
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
    BOOL fReturn = FALSE;
    BOOL fResult;
    DWORD dwSize;

    __try
 {
        *pCounterSignerInfo = NULL;

        // Loop through unathenticated attributes for
        // szOID_RSA_counterSign OID.
        for (DWORD n = 0; n < pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.cAttr; n++)
        {
            if (lstrcmpA(pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].pszObjId,
            szOID_RSA_counterSign) == 0)
            {
                // Get size of CMSG_SIGNER_INFO structure.
                fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO,
                pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                0,
                NULL,
                &dwSize);
                if (!fResult)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                    GetLastError());
                    __leave;
                }

                // Allocate memory for CMSG_SIGNER_INFO.
                *pCounterSignerInfo = (PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSize);
                if (!*pCounterSignerInfo)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for timestamp info.\n"));
                    __leave;
                }

                // Decode and get CMSG_SIGNER_INFO structure
                // for timestamp certificate.
                fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO,
                pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                0,
                (PVOID) * pCounterSignerInfo,
                &dwSize);
                if (!fResult)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                    GetLastError());
                    __leave;
                }

                fReturn = TRUE;

                break; // Break from for loop.
            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        // Clean up.
        if (pCertContext != NULL) CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
    }

    return fReturn;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/get-information-authenticode-signed-executables  and thanks for the picture it looks like the "Subject Name" is what I'm after, go figure.

Comment: @user3161924 -- ah there it is. I have used this code in a production environment across many clients and have never had an issue. So it's pretty solid.